# I Want to create custom Circular Button which will Focus on click how to do?

Tags: android

I am trying to create one custom button which is circular and when i click that button i want that button FOCUS and COLOR change and i don't know how to do exactly so any one can help me or show me that code how to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular `Button` and specify custom Drawable for it and then apply it to the Background property of the button. See the ApiDemos for examples of styling controls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two (or more) drawables for one Button and change the drawables in various states (focus, press, etc). Look at this: http://blog.androgames.net/40/custom-button-style-and-theme/